# payumoney post integration in android.error

Tags: payment, gateway, payu

Hello I am integrating payumoney in app and when i'm trying to post all fields to URL it says that `Sorry, some problem occurred`.

Below i am pasting my code.

```
gen Hash();
String post Data = "hash=hash&key=key&txnid=txnid&amount=amount&product info=product info&first name=first name&email=email&contact=contact&SALT=SALT&SURL=SURL&FURL= FURL";
web View = (Web View) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64"));

public void genHash() {
    try {   
        hash = sha512.sha512(key + "|" + txnid + "|" + amount + "|"
                    + productinfo + "|" + firstname + "|" + email
                    + "|||||||||||" + SALT);

    } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {        
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }

    System.out.println(hash);
}
```

Comment: Hi Akshat, May i know in payumoney integration kit which kit you have choosen? is it JSP?   Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Akshat, i have asked this question in a separate thread,     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575260/payumoney-payment-integration-for-android-app                                                           please replay, i am ready to give bounty or whatever it takes, plz help me with this i am stuck from 4days.

Comment: Hi Akshat, can you pls post sha512.sha512 method thnx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

While posting the data to PayUMoney you are not posting a **mandatory** parameter named `service_provider`
whose value is always `payu_paisa`.
So for this reason you are getting this error.

Regards,
PayUMoney Integration Team

Comment: Hello Andy, the document which i have got from the payu has not got any parameter as of service_provider.

Comment: Hello Andy, when i am trying with the post parameter as service_provider and with value pau_paisa. I am still getting on the page like Sorry, some problem occurred.

Comment: @AkshatSharma, I also ran into same problem. Their support people said that you need to get a Test Merchant ID. The one provided in documentation isn't working. Try registering [Test Merchant Account](https://test.payumoney.com/)

Comment: @RaviDhoriyaツ Thanks for the suggestion. It is done as of now. I was passing an extra parameter service_provider. I removed it and now it is working fine.

Comment: @RaviDhoriya , i what parameter name can i pass my merchant id