# PayU Payment Integration in Android Issue

Tags: android, webview, payment, gateway, payu

I am trying to integrate `Payment Gateway (PayU)` in Android through `WebView`.
I am able to send the data to the `PayU` through POST.
After successful transaction, the page is not redirecting to the "surl" i.e successUrl / "furl" i.e FailureUrl. It always shows page not found.

Following is the code of `WebView`:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
String postData = "Required Data sent to PayU by POST";
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
         Log.d("Page_Started",url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         Log.d("Page_Finished",url);
    }
});

webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);       //Zoom Control on web (You don't need this
//if ROM supports Multi-Touch
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.postUrl(action, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```

In Log, its not showing any success url / failure url. I always get a message from `PayU` that `Page Not Found-404`

Do I have to make some changes in webView?
Its working perfect in `WebPage`, not working in Android.

Comment: facing similar issue, is there a proper technical documentation for android anywhere?

Comment: You can find it here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383216/payumoney-post-integration-in-android-error

Comment: You can find it here.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383216/payumoney-post-integration-in-android-error]

Answer (score 0):

After transaction Payu **POST** the transaction status response back your surl/furl according to the transaction status.

Please make sure that your surl/furl accept POST request.

Answer (score 0):

After a long searching and changing in code. Finally, i got proper solution of this problem. For testing just you this parameters, **merchant key:"gtKFFx" , salt: "eCwWELxi"**. After launching payumoney screen. To enter debit card details use this details, **Name on Card: Any name, Card Number: 5123456789012346, CVV: 123, Expiry Date: 05/2017**. When i used this credentials and numbers it working very well and redirecting to my particular success URL.

Comment: Hi Ronak, I'm using non-seamless integration using PayU sdk. I'm still getting same error even after using above credentials. can you help?

Comment: I have not use PayU sdk. Try to use the webview for this and then use this credentials.